# Correct way of Deploying to production using CI/CD server

Tags: git, deployment, continuous-integration

I have been working with software development for a while but the release procedure I've been doing has been fairly manual where I build locally and then SFTP the output to the production servers. Although this has worked it is a bit of a pain, so I'm looking at ways of automating it using a CI/CD server.

I've been using TeamCity for a while, although not really for releases, more of just a way to test builds and dependencies automatically but would still just copy the build output and SFTP to a server.

I am using GitHub for the source control, and what I've seen that normally everything in the master/main branch is what gets auto published to production. This is the opposite of what I'd learnt and done previously as the main/master was the active dev branch for quick fixes, any major changes or feature requests would be branched from main/master and then once complete pulled back to the master, and then the master is tagged, and then the tag is what goes to production, but from what I've seen, tags aren't really used that often, other than to have a snapshot of what the master/main branch was at a given time. Is this understanding correct or have I missed something.

If this is correct, is there a generic guide someone can point me in, how do I get my production servers to automatically fetch the master when the CI/CD server runs its tests and build how would I get the build output pushed to production. I work with projects such as ReactJS, Laravel and C# .Net Core if that makes any difference.

I guess from what I've read, I could have main/master which gets pushed to production, a staging branch which gets auto pushed to my staging environment and a dev branch for local development and then when a feature branch is pushed to staging, the CI/CD server would auto push the build output to the staging environment and the same for when main/master pulls from staging but not sure how this automatic push to the different environments are done.

Comment: I've read this about 3 times - I'm not sure if its me being stupid but; what is your question exactly?

Comment: Its in the second to last paragraph, basically if someone can point me in the right direction on how automatic deployment of releases are done using a CI/CD server such as TeamCity to push releases to production, staging etc.

Comment: What is your production environment? Are you using Docker/Kubernetes/IIS on a server etc?

Comment: No nothing like that, its just simple Linux web server (Apache) and currently just upload the project build output folders from my dev box to the prod server and route them through Apache.

Comment: @Boardy see my article here for context - https://worklifenotes.com/2020/06/04/7-best-practices-modern-cicd/ - and then feel free to reach out to me at DevOps Community for specific questions - https://devopscommunity.org